# Add docstring to a namedtuple field

Tags: python, namedtuple

I know it is possible to add docstring for namedtuples by subclassing it, e.g.

```
from collections import namedtuple
NT = namedtuple('NT', ['f1', 'f2', 'f3'])
class NTWithDoc(NT):
    """ DOCSTRING """
    __slots__ = ()
```

Now I wish to add docstring for f1, f2, and f3. Is there a way of doing that? Our company is using Python2, don't think people will let me use 3.

Comment: note, you don't need a `pass` in that code :-)

Comment: anyways are you using py 2 or py 3

Comment: Does [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606436/adding-docstrings-to-namedtuples) cover the problem?

Comment: @alecxe -- I don't see it there.  That's basically what OP already knows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a good way to do this on python2.x.  On python3.x, you can swap out the `__doc__` directly:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.0a2 (v3.6.0a2:378893423552, Jun 13 2016, 14:44:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> NT = namedtuple('NT', ['f1', 'f2', 'f3'])
>>> NT.f1.__doc__
'Alias for field number 0'
>>> NT.f1.__doc__ = 'Hello'
```

Unfortunately, python2.x gives you an error at this point:

```
>>> NT.f1.__doc__ = 'Hello World.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: readonly attribute
```

On python2.x, you can get it by re-defining all of the properties:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> NT = namedtuple('NT', ['f1', 'f2', 'f3'])
>>> class NTWithDoc(NT):
...     """docstring."""
...     __slots__ = ()
...     f1 = property(NT.f1.fget, None, None, 'docstring!')
... 
>>> help(NTWithDoc)

>>> a = NTWithDoc(1, 2, 3)
>>> a.f1
1
```

But this feels like a lot of trouble to go to get the docstrings :-).

Comment: That is why I ask... Forgot to mention Python version is 2.

Comment: @xis -- I've added a python2.x variant (I thought of it on my walk home from work).